# There is an unknown device on my WLAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

I recently discovered something a little concerning I guess. There seems to be a device/client on my WLAN that I don't know and cannot identify as it says it is called 'localhost' (and sometimes it says 'unknown'). It has the IP 192.168.0.10 which is one of the most common to my knowledge. None of my devices use or used that IP. I first thought that 'localhost' could be some kind of 'artefact' because I sometimes run node.js/XAMPP locally (altough I am aware that localhost runs on 127.0.0.1). I now am certain that it is none of these which is why I came here for help! I hope someone had a similar issue/knows what this could mean.

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: If you’re seeing this through your router could you check and verify it’s MAC address that it doesn’t belong to you as a first step. If not i recommend changing you router passsword and WiFi password and disable wps.

Comment: I just now disabled WPS and suddenly the device vanished! Wow is it possible that someone else paired a wireless access point ore something similar with my router? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It is possible that someone used a wps attack method to obtain access to your wlan anyways glad I could help .

Comment: Well thank you so much! Problem solved I hope.. finally!

Comment: How did you discover this device? I ask because there's at least one place in Windows where it will show you nearby devices that are NOT on your network, in case you want to trigger WPS to help *get* them onto your network. But the Windows UI doesn't make this clear, so people think those devices were already on their network, when they weren't.